# How to install just angular-ui-router.js file instead of entire source code solution from npm?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angular-ui-router

When I installed `angular` package from node package manager(`npm`), I got required **JS** files under *angular* root directory.

```
$npm install angular
```

But, when I'm installing `angular-ui-router` package, I got entire source code solution and required **JS** files located under *release* directory.

```
$npm install angular-ui-router
```

Is there any way to install required **JS** files from `npm`, instead of entire source code solution?

Comment: can use cdn version if you want or manually download or bower...lots of ways to do it

Comment: @charlietfl, both `bower` and `npm` reacts the same way! (both are installing the entire solution)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `npm install angular-ui-router` you will get exactly what was published to npm so it is dependend on the publisher. You can use cdn as was suggested in a comment under you question like:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js
```

Or just manualy delete files you don't need in `node_modules` folder.

Btw, why exactly you need to do this ? Is it because of concatenation of vendor libraries so you get more code in final artifact or do you deploy `node_modules` folder?

Comment: I'm going to concatenate only required JS files; Why are they providing the entire code solution to the user? Is there any special purpose??

Comment: I suppose that similarly to bower packages (which are stored ad github), also npm packages usualy have respective gihub repository. It's open source software, that means you can build it yourself from the sources you can read. Because of this you can be sure that you are using exactly that code and no 3rd party created some malicious distribution files.

Comment: I thought, there is no possibility of malicious effect; because, for angular package I can only get required JS files instead of the entire solution. I guess, they might publish the entire source code instead of the required files on npm!

Comment: Well some repositories, if yopu check their owner can be proved secure just by that fact, but that mehchanism i described works in general for any open source, build it your self from the provided source to be sure :)